# The difference beetween 'nasty' and 'horrible' or 'terrible'

Tags: meaning

For the most situations adjectives 'horrible' and 'terrible' are synonyms. But I often come across with word 'nasty' with similar meaning like 'nasty cough', 'nasty smell'. Is there any difference or 'nasty' is the same like 'terrible' (or 'horrible')?

Answer (score 2):

Rarely are synonyms considered 100% interchangable in all contexts. These three words can all mean *bad* or *unpleasant*, so there is going to be a lot of overlapping meaning between them.

If we were describing a cough, a smell, or a dirty floor, these words might be considered somewhat interchangable.

That said, if you were asking me about a film that I thought had a boring plot, bad acting, and an awful script, I might say:

> *The Last Airbender* was a terrible film!

but I'd be unlikely to say:

> *The Last Airbender* was a nasty film!

When talking about movies, the word *nasty* would be reserved for something that was disgusting for some reason. So, I might say:

> *Saw IV* was a nasty film. Too much violence and gore for my tastes.

People often find ways to stretch words like these beyond their normal usages. For example, if a pitcher throws a *nasty* pitch, it means the pitch was hard to hit. Most pitchers would consider it a compliment, though it's hard to find much complimentary language in the word's [definition](https://www.wordnik.com/words/nasty). Here's a [scouting report](http://jaysjournal.com/2014/03/24/2014-toronto-blue-jays-top-prospects-1-aaron-sanchez-scouting-report-stats-projection-eta/) where the word was used in this fashion:

> He posted a 2.49 ERA that season and struck out nearly 10 batters per nine but struggled with control, which led to him walking more than half as many as he K’d. When he was assigned to the High-A Dunedin Blue Jays to start 2013, the hope was he would take strides to clean up his control by learning to harness his **nasty** stuff.
>
> He was basically unhittable the first six weeks of the season and was holding opponents to a .166 batting average (and 9.5% walk rate)

We can't substitute *terrible* or *horrible* into that context, because baseball pundits don't use those words to describe hard-to-hit baseballs in a complimentary fashion.

There are other differences as well, but they probably can't all be listed exhaustively here. Learning when two words can be swapped requires experience, or else careful study of the various definitions of the word in dictionaries, where you can pick up on the subtle nuances of each. [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/horrible) is a great place to start, as it uses definitions from a few different dictionaries, and lists some examples usages as well.

Comment: The 'nasty' pitch is from the point of view of the batter.  If you use 'terrible' or 'horrible' it would always be from the pitcher's point of view.  So a nasty pitch would get an out, a terrible one would lead to a home run.

Comment: @Oldcat - True. It's from the batter's point of view (which is why I called them "hard-to-hit baseballs").

Answer (score 0):

'Nasty' usually means *offensive* or even *malicious* (while speaking of persons). But I guess 'nasty' is sometimes used as a synonym for 'horrible' too. [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/nasty) lists 'horrible' (also 'terrible' in the sense 'awful') as a synonym for 'nasty'.

**Edit:** And if you consider [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nasty,horrible,%20terrible&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,nasty;,c0;.t1;,horrible;,c0;.t1;,terrible;,c0) a reliable source of reference, you would see that *terrible* is more commonly used than the other two.

Answer (score -1):

Nasty  is frequently intentional,(but occasionally unintentional), offensive or even intentional harm.horrible is uncontrollable extreme harmful behavior and harmful behavior worsened events.terrible is intentional extreme harmful behavior,which controlled.nasty attack by emotional  or mental ill person victimized by evil gang.horrible ☹️deadly and destructive—hurricanes,which catastrophic deadly effected humanity because governments terrible generational policies continued to support polluting private industries  and overpopulation .

Comment: Are the distinctions you mention in your response simply personal observations, or are do they reflect information you've found in reputable reference works? If the latter, please identify the sources and consider quoting their corroborating definitions or comments.